# JQuery animate behaviour with inline-block elements

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using JQuery to animate two divs, one on top of the other, inside a another div. The effect is like a button with the top and bottom halves opening up and down to reveal some contents. The idea is to have a number of these 'buttons' in line using `float:left`

When a button is clicked, the script checks if another button is open, if so, closes that button and opens the clicked button.

This works fine, except I want to change `float:left` to `display:inline-block` on the container div class (to prevent wrapping of a number of buttons if the browser is resized).  The problem is the layout of buttons breaks as JQuery animate seems to be changing the vertical position of the button containers while animating.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2tz0k8q/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.btn{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2tz0k8q/2/)